# RTL: Unable to find role "form" from Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, formik

So I'm new to RTL library and what I wanted to do is to test validations in my Formik Form.

The component looks like this:

```
export const SignUp = () => {
  const handleSubmit = ({ username, password, email }: SignUpInitialValues) => {
    action(SignUpSlice.CREATE_ACCOUNT, { username, password, email });
  };

  const initialValues: SignUpInitialValues = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    email: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
  };

  return (
    <SectionWrapper>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={signUpValidationSchema}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <Form className="mx-auto max-w-3xl rounded-lg bg-white px-6 py-12 shadow-lg md:px-12">
            <SignUpForm />
            <SubmitFormButton
              text="Create account"
              disabled={FormUtils.isFormInvalid<SignUpInitialValues>(formik)}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </SectionWrapper>
  );
};
```

And I have some jest tests failing due to the error

> Error: Unable to find role="form"

Provided tests are as below:

```
const renderComponent = () => render(<SignUp />);

  const prefillForm = async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const password = faker.random.word();
    const username = faker.random.word();
    const email = faker.internet.email();

    await user.type(await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/Email/), email);
    await user.type(await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/Username/), username);
    await user.type(await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/^Password$/), password);
    await user.type(
      await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/Confirm Password/),
      password
    );

    return { user, username, password, email };
  };

  const invalidActions = [
    async (user: UserEvent) => {
      const component = await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/Email/);
      await user.clear(component);
      await user.type(component, faker.random.word());
    },
    async (user: UserEvent) => {
      const component = await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/Username/);
      await user.clear(component);
      await user.type(component, 's');
    },
    async (user: UserEvent) =>
      user.type(
        await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/^Password$/),
        faker.random.word()
      ),
    async (user: UserEvent) =>
      user.type(
        await screen.findByPlaceholderText(/Confirm Password/),
        faker.random.word()
      ),
  ];

  it.each(invalidActions)(
    'Should provide invalid payload',
    async (invalidAction) => {
      renderComponent();

      const { user } = await prefillForm();
      await invalidAction(user);

      await waitFor(() =>
        expect(screen.getByRole('button')).toHaveAttribute('disabled')
      );
    }
  );
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Am I missing some await in the assertion or is it just a Formik bug and I should find a different way of handling this?

On top of that I'd add only third test is always failing - not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to fix these tests.

Adding `form` attribute to the `Form` Formik component worked like a charm:

```
<Form
            role="form"
            className="mx-auto max-w-3xl rounded-lg bg-white px-6 py-12 shadow-lg md:px-12"
          >
            <SignUpForm />
            <SubmitFormButton
              text="Create account"
              disabled={FormUtils.isFormInvalid<SignUpInitialValues>(formik)}
            />
          </Form>
```

But if anyone knows why this was happening I'd be more than happy to know as I thought this should be handled by default by formik library.